# Second derivative of a Laguerre polynomial: Show that $L_n''(0)=\frac{1}{2}n(n-1).$

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, special-functions

> Show that
>   $$L_n''(0)=\frac{1}{2}n(n-1)$$

My first thought was to use the recurrence relation $$L_n^k(x)=L_{n-1}^k(x)+L_n^{k-1}(x)$$ and the orthogonality property
$$\int_0^\infty e^{-x} x^kL_n^k(x)L_m^k(x)dx=\frac{(n+k)1}{n!},$$
for $k=2$, but doing so didn't seem to lead anywhere.

Comment: Which definition of Laguerre polynomials do you have? If you start from the series form of it then it's just true by definition; if you start from the generating function then I think it's also fairly obvious. (If it's from a recurrence relation, on the other hand, then it's not as immediate and your approach seems like the right idea.)

Comment: I assume I can't start from the series form, because like you say there's no work involved. The problem doesn't specify however. So I should start from the generating function? Also I just realised that "1" after the (n+k) should be "!".

Comment: Well, the generating function $$g(x,z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty L_n(x)z^n=\frac{\exp\left(-\frac{x z}{1-z}\right)}{1-z}.$$ Taking two $x$-derivatives and evaluating at $x=0$ then gives a generating function for $L_n''(0)$. So that method is fairly straightforward. _But_ if you don't have the GF already then this isn't a good method!

Comment: @MyGlasses No, it indicates that these are the associated Laguerre polynomials $L_n^k(x)$. (For $k=0$ these are just Laguerre polynomials.) But that should probably be clarified in the question...

Comment: I had the same question about k; I thought it was the order of the derivative. That's very helpful, thanks. And yes, I believe I can use the generating function.

Comment: Actually neither of these generating functions works. The first doesn't give L in terms of n, and the second always has that x term, so it all becomes 0 for x=0.

Answer (score 1):

We know $L_n(0)=1$ and $L'_n(0)=-n$, so by derivation of Laguerre equation
$$xy''+(1-x)y'+ny=0$$
again and set $x=0$ you will find it.

Comment: Do you mean to solve the differential equation again?

Comment: No. Just differentiate $y''+xy'''+(-1)y'+(1-x)y''+ny'=0$.

Answer (score 1):

$$L_n(x)=\Sigma_{k=0}^{n}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\left ( \begin{align*}n \\k \end{align*} \right )x^k.$$ With $k=2$, we have $\left ( \begin{align*} n \\ \ 2 \end{align*} \right)=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}, (-1)^2=1, k!=2, x^2.$ So $$\frac{d}{dx}\left[ \frac{n(n-1)}{4}x^2\right ]=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}x,$$
and $$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\left [ \frac{n(n-1)}{2}x\right ] = \frac{1}{2}n(n-1).$$